# What is the best way to pass parameters to the application?

Tags: c#, software-design

I'm writing an command line application which will take a lot of input from the user. Example input should contain:

- Connection strings to RDB/Cube
- parameters used for queries
- queries
- XPath stings
- Some boolean valued parameters
- paths for WebService items

I'm wondering what is the best approach to pass them all to the program. I'm sure that queries, XPaths and parameters should be stored in a file, but should they be contained in a single file? What about the rest, is it better to pass them as a command line parameters or should I prepare a file for them as well?

What is the best/most common approach for this kind of situation?

Comment: Hard to answer without more context. Will the parameters be shared across mulitple user/instance? Will the parameter be reused in a scheduled task? Do you have a DB in the application? Is there any graphical tool? What is the skills of the users? ...

Comment: The app connects to standalone SQL server instance and its meant for batch testing, so all the input must be ready before launching. There won't be any GUI and each launch of the app will share only connection strings, everything else will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i did this kind of application I started from usual command line parameters and added ability to load parameter values from file like:

```
 app.exe -ConnectionString "...." -Query file(query.xml) -AnotherQuery "SELECT * FROM Table"
```

So you can let user to decide where to store different parameters.